# Even if async: true I keep getting error about "synchronous" XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My problem is that even if I have async: true in my ajax GET request I keep getting information that my AJAX request is synchronous. The funny thing is that it sometimes works in that single case :)

In the scroll event it works perfectly, I mean that after scroll and -150px to bottom I have no errors while I'm requesting more rows to my list, but when I have something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.ion-chevron-right', function() {
    if($('.list div:nth-last-child(3)').hasClass('active')){
        GetList();
    }
    console.log('here');
    $('.col.next h3 .trgclik').click();
});
```

it sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. I have even added cache: false to AJAX call but nothing, I still keep getting errors (not all the time).

I have to add that this button ".ion-chevron-right" is in other element which is loading also by AJAX but this "click" event I put in my main file in which I have also scroll method in which AJAX works perfectly, maybe this is the reason?

EDIT:

This is the second function which loads other element in which I have that button:

```
var Preview =  {
    beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
    success:        showResponse,
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    complete: function(){
        console.log('it works');
    },
    url:            'deletedForStack',       
    type:           'post'
}
```

Comment: Can you add GetList function? And if possible the backend code

Comment: tbh I can't put here my backend code :/ so I added more JS code